# Pycharm Linux. How to change color scheme of selected file in Project Inspetor

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pycharm, color-scheme

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkHjU.png]

As you can see, I cant recognize text on selected .py file. How to change the color?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please note that questions with links to code or images tend to get down votes. So it is best to include all the relevant data in the post.

Comment: @hotzst - Images _of code_ are the problem. In this instance, an image is perfectly acceptable, since the issue involves color schemes in a GUI.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 the image is acceptable, because I changed from the linked image (should have mentioned that).

Comment: How is this too broad?

Answer (score 1):

Note: using the 5.0.2 Pro version.

You can customize the colors of the file displays (actually just the unselected background colors, the selected one seems adjusted automatically) via `File Colors` settings:

[image]

You can also use a less dark appearance theme in which colors are easier to distinguish (personally I prefer `IntelliJ`):

[image]

Update:

I just stumbled on this JetBrains [tutorial on PyCharm appearance](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=51945983) which includes coverage of exactly this subject.